# React component inside interpolated React Component

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple `<Trans/>` React Component which allows to translate a key with some properties (I use sprintf). For example:

```
<Trans planet="World">Hello %(planet)s</Trans>
```

renders:

> Hello World

The issue is when trying to render some of those properties dynamically, say instead of "World" I want to have

```
<Trans color="blue">%(color)s planet</Trans>
```

Now, what react does is first outputting the following:

> Hello [object Object]

Before going down the render path and correctly render

> Hello blue planet

This results in a little flickr of showing [object Object] instead of the rendered element. I have tried to use renderToString, but then it would force me to use some dangerouslySetInnerHTML which doesn't work with other translation constrains.

Any thoughts?

```
import React, {PropTypes, Component} from 'react'
import {sprintf} from 'sprintf-js'

export default class Trans extends Component {
  translate(key, args){
    if(this.props.context && this.props.context[key]) key = this.props.context[key]
    else console.error('%s is not in translated keys', key, ' - context was ', this.props.context)
    if(typeof key === 'object' && key.singular){
      if(this.props.isPlural)
        return sprintf(key.plural, args)
      else
        return sprintf(key.singular, args)
    }
    return sprintf(key, args)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <span>
        {this.translate(this.props.children, this.props)}
      </span>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: `<Trans color="blue">%(color)s planet</Trans> `whats mean dynamically? looks the same as `<Trans planet="World">Hello %(planet)s</Trans>` but with the different props names.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the `#toString()` method on the color prototype returns what you want.

Comment: Sorry I should have included so whole class in there from the first place, but just added it now. There is no toString method - its just a sprintf function replacing keys in the props.children by the data passed as props.